# How to get rid of plotly bar chart background color

Tags: plotly

I have the following code:

```
def get_amp_graph():
            ampfig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=['1540', 'Average'], y=get_amp_acc()))
            ampfig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgb(28, 28, 28)')
            amp_html = ampfig.to_html (
                include_plotlyjs=True, 
                full_html=False,
                
            )
            return amp_html
```

I want the background color to be rgb(28, 28, 28), but then [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeVqf.png). How could I make the remaining white also turn rgb(28, 28, 28)